# Facebook user id on iframe page tab without permissions

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I have a fair amount of Facebook development experience, but this had made me pull my hair. It must be something very small, but I can't get it. I recently saw some Facebook pages with welcome tabs that show user's name "Welcome [YOUR NAME]" who visits their page. Example is here:

https://www.facebook.com/Tony.Samaha.Official.Page

As per my knowledge, we cannot get the user id without the permissions by the user. After the permissions we are able to get the user id in the signed request. How do I get the Facebook user id or name, something similar to the above example? How is this working? Can this be achieved?

FYI: I am using iframe tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user is still using the old static [FBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#FBML) application, so most likely they are using the `fb:name` tag. Though, I believe this is now deprecated. So really, the page you linked to needs to be updated.

Comment: Hmmm i think you are right. "fb:name" can still be used for a while. So there is no way to get the user id without permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the documentation on [signed_requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).  When a user visits your application there will be a `signed_request` posted to your URL. The documentation states :

> - A signed_request is passed to Apps on Facebook.com when they are
>     loaded into the Facebook environment
> - A signed_request is passed to any
>     app that has registered an Deauthorized Callback in the Developer App
>     whenever a given user removes the app using the App Dashboard
> - A signed_request is passed to apps that use the Registration Plugin
>     whenever a user successfully registers with their app

You will have to decode this request (see the link above for details) and from there you will be able to extract the user_id of the visiting user.  Then all you have to do is query the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) like this :
`https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID` and you will get back the public information for that user which *should* include the users name.

Comment: You are right but that need permissions before you can get the "user id" part of the signed request

Comment: If you are talking about a page tab app - all the user needs to do is "like" the page and you will have access to his user id

Comment: Are you receiving the signed request? Are you able to parse it?

Comment: Yes, sure, I'm a admin of the fan page and i can parse signed_request. This is my signed request: `### SIGNED REQUEST ###  Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 [issued_at] => 1330112620 [page] => Array ( [id] => 304887859549216 [liked] => 1 [admin] => 1 )  [user] => Array ( [country] => us [locale] => en_US [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 )  )  ) `

Comment: Test app: http://goo.gl/1bNco Debug info available for Admins by pressing "©" symbol in the footer.

Comment: why don't you update your post with the relevant code that you are using to retrieve and parse the signed request.

Comment: Sure, here it is: `require_once "../api/facebook.php";

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => APP_ID,
  'secret' => SECRET,
  'cookie' => true
 ));
 
 $signedrequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();`